# Ruby iterating in a class method while referencing another class

Tags: ruby, class, methods

Solved. I didn't have the initialization right, which gave the noMethodError. Then I was changing an array, but checking a variable that referred to a position in the array, and that variable had not been reassigned.

Edited to initialize bookPagesInfo, bookChaptersInfo, editPagesInfo, and editChapterInfo as suggested. Still gives the same NoMethod Error.

I have a book with page and chapter info, and want to be able to apply edits that change the number of pages, introPages, chapters, and povs.

```rb
class Book
    attr_accessor :pages, :chapters, :bookPagesInfo, :bookChaptersInfo, :introPages, :povs

    def initialize(bookPagesInfo, bookChaptersInfo)
        @bookPagesInfo = bookPagesInfo
        @bookChaptersInfo = bookChaptersInfo
        @pages = bookPagesInfo[0]
        @introPages = bookPagesInfo[1]
        @chapters = bookChaptersInfo[0]
        @povs = bookChaptersInfo[1]
    end
    
    def applyEdit(edit)
        @pages += edit.new_pages
    end
end

class Edit       
    attr_accessor :new_pages, :new_chapters, :editPagesInfo, :editChaptersInfo, :new_intro_pages, :new_povs

    def initialize(editPagesInfo, editChaptersInfo)
        @editPagesInfo = editPagesInfo
        @editChaptersInfo = editChaptersInfo
        @new_pages = editPagesInfo[0]
        @new_intro_pages = editPagesInfo[1]
        @new_chapters = editChaptersInfo[0]
        @new_povs = editChaptersInfo[1]
    end
end
```

The above code works for editing just number of pages. However, if I change my applyEdit method to iterate over the bookPagesInfo array, I can't get it to work. Running applyEdit below gives a nonfatal error.

```rb
    def applyEdit(edit)
        @bookPagesInfo.each_with_index do {|stat, idx| stat += edit.bookPagesInfo[idx]}    
    end
        ## gives undefined method `each_with_index' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError), but 
        ## my understanding is as long as bookPagesInfo was initialized as an array, it 
        ## should be an array, not nilClass
```

I'm pretty new to classes (and this website, sorry for formatting). Thanks for the help.

Comment: As you have the "attr_accessor" to edit the instance variables inside the constructer method, you need not to create any separate method for read or write the instance var available in class. use this syntax to edit. Syntax:   class object.instance variable = new value  #=> this ill change the value of that instance.
if this is not which you are asking for then come again more clearly by improving your question

Answer (score 0):

You've got `attr_accessor`s defined for `:bookPagesInfo` and `:bookChaptersInfo`, which will give you reader and writer methods, but it won't set `@bookPagesInfo` and `@bookChaptersInfo` for you in the `initialize` method - you need to do that yourself.  So, when you try to read from the instance variable in `applyEdit`, you're reading `nil`.

Try adding

```rb
  @bookPagesInfo = bookPagesInfo
  @bookChaptersInfo = bookChaptersInfo
```

in `Book#initialize`.

Comment: Did this and it still gets a NoMethodError

Comment: show your code with the updates that @Simon suggested and the error you get with those updates

Comment: Edited original

Comment: Is it the same NoMethodError at `each_with_index` or is it a different method that's missing?

Comment: It's the same NoMethodError at each_with_index

Comment: I think we need to see more code, then, so we can know what's getting passed into your constructor.